# What to do about questions asking for RNG seeds?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Isn't a [question asking for a seed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32244/how-can-i-generate-a-waterfall) just yet another [....-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/....-rec) question?  While there is certainly an objective answer (one that minimally meets the specified criteria), there are also near-as-makes-no-difference an infinite amount of answers and judging which is the best (ostensibly the point of votes) is totally subjective.

Comment: It is both a list question and a rec questions and should be closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what I said when they first came up on [this horrible question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19962/minecraft-seeds-for-a-high-landscape).

These are **off topic** and should be closed.